# Build action is not supported

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

No code, since it's not a code problem, rather a visual studio one.

I've searched this problem up a bit and found people saying they had this problem, not really specifying how they got it, and most people answering "you should set AndroidManifest.xml's build actions to none" without any explanation of why this would work, which, well won't work for me since it's already what I have and I'm getting the error anyway.

How I came to have this problem:
I made a few files, file1, file2, file3, in my assets directory.
I would then read them with a streamreader. This worked.

Fast forward a few weeks, I decide to rename them, through visual studio, to file1.txt, file2.txt ... etc.

When I compiled/launched it on my device, it did not work. An exception on streamreader told me the file wasn't found. And before that I had 3 errors "@(Content)build action is not supported" for each of my files.

I assume the problem lies in the build actions or possibly the way android behaves with some specific files? Either way how could this have changed by changing the file format? I made them .txt files for clarity purposes, I didn't expect everything to break down after that.

Ontop of that, I could not revert it. I removed the file extensions, and I still have the same problem now.

What should I do to have my files in the assets folder properly deployed on my machine just like they used to ? Is it related to the build options?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assets should have a build action of AndroidAsset.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/android-assets?tabs=windows

Comment: @jason thanks, I assume this was the way it was before I edited them. I have  no idea why these settings were changed by vs after I renamed the files.

Answer (score 1):

As highlighted by Jason in the comments above, the build actions for android assets should be AndroidAsset, which got changed after I renamed them. This menu can be found on the properties of the file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/android-assets?tabs=windows

Comment: This fixed it for me after numerous other massive headaches with Android that were resolved; I had assets leftover from the project after updating and this AndroidAsset was not an available option before, so this fixed it right away.